# How do I create a json in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I have some clojurescript that I want to interop with some javascript libraries. In my clojurescript code I do some analysis and come up with a list of maps.
something like

```
[{:prop1 "value1" :prop2 "value2"}, {:prop1 "something else" :prop2 "etc"}...]
```

I need to pass this to a javascript functions as

```
[{prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2}, {..} ...]
```

I'm not sure how to return a javascript object form my clojurescript function though. Is there a way to serialize nested maps and lists to javascript objects. Or a way to create a new javascript object and then set properties on it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a function [here](http://techylinguist.com/posts/2012/01/23/clojurescript-getting-started)

```
(defn clj->js
  "Recursively transforms ClojureScript maps into Javascript objects,
   other ClojureScript colls into JavaScript arrays, and ClojureScript
   keywords into JavaScript strings.

   Borrowed and updated from mmcgrana."
  [x]
  (cond
    (string? x) x
    (keyword? x) (name x)
    (map? x) (.-strobj (reduce (fn [m [k v]]
               (assoc m (clj->js k) (clj->js v))) {} x))
    (coll? x) (apply array (map clj->js x))
    :else x))
```

Does exactly what I needed. There is also the inverse function, namely `js->clj` in ClojureScript core.

Comment: Your map conversion is exploiting an implementation detail of SOME cljs maps. It won't always work. Use this gist instead: https://gist.github.com/3153856

Comment: @Brian -- looks like the `clj->js` in your gist doesn't actually use the `map->js` in your gist, unless I missed the intent?

Answer (score 49):

Just for the sake of people looking for something similar.

The ClojureScript core now contains a [`clj->js`](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/clj-GTjs) function.

Comment: Does it answer the question?

Comment: It does: `(.stringify js/JSON (clj->js {:key "value"}))` -> `"{\"key\":\"value\"}"`

Answer (score 12):

This works for me:

```
(defn clj->json
  [ds]
  (.stringify js/JSON (clj->js ds)))
```

usage:

```
(let [json (clj->json data-structure)]
  ;; do something with json
  )
```

Comment: I like to pretty-print my json when running in test so it's more readable. To do this, add arguments to the .stringify line: `(.stringify js/JSON (clj->js ds) nil 2)` The nil is a replacer which will be unused, and the 2 means two spaces for each level of indent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify