# Parse Clojure Script to JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, clojure, clojurescript

I have a clojure data in the form of clojure format.

```
[{:dt [2017 6 30], :cashflow 431782} {:dt [2018 6 30], :cashflow 452271} {:dt [2019 6 30], :cashflow 473785} {:dt [2020 6 30], :cashflow 496374}]
```

I want the above clojure data in the form json. from clojure side i can always use Cheshire. But I would like tto do it on the lient side in javascript

Comment: so on client/js you'd have your data/input as string ? i.e. `"[{:dt [2017 6 30], :cashflow 431782} {:dt [2018...` and want to parse that ?

Comment: @birdspider yes

Comment: and you want it as cljs data or explicitly as json ?

Comment: @birdspider i want to parse this cljs to json explicitly. Is there a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As illustrated in this [question (`cljs.reader/read-string`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208287/stringify-parse-edn-in-clojure-clojurescript) and [this (`clj->js`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157447/how-do-i-create-a-json-in-clojurescript) the following should do the trick:

```
cljs.user=> (def data-as-str 
  "[{:dt [2017 6 30], :cashflow 431782}
    {:dt [2018 6 30], :cashflow 452271}
    {:dt [2019 6 30], :cashflow 473785}
    {:dt [2020 6 30], :cashflow 496374}]")
#'cljs.user/data-as-str

cljs.user=> (cljs.reader/read-string data-as-str)
[{:dt [2017 6 30], :cashflow 431782}
 {:dt [2018 6 30], :cashflow 452271}
 {:dt [2019 6 30], :cashflow 473785}
 {:dt [2020 6 30], :cashflow 496374}]

; i have little experience in cljs but this should deliver
; a plain old js object
cljs.user=> (clj->js (cljs.reader/read-string data-as-str))
#js [#js {:dt #js [2017 6 30], :cashflow 431782}
     #js {:dt #js [2018 6 30], :cashflow 452271}
     #js {:dt #js [2019 6 30], :cashflow 473785}
     #js {:dt #js [2020 6 30], :cashflow 496374}]
```

from here on you could do whatever JSON.___ or other js-json lib provides

for example:

```
cljs.user=> (.stringify js/JSON 
              (clj->js (cljs.reader/read-string data-as-str)))
"[{\"dt\":[2017,6,30],\"cashflow\":431782},{\"dt\":[2018,6,30],\"cashflow\":452271},{\"dt\":[2019,6,30],\"cashflow\":473785},{\"dt\":[2020,6,30],\"cashflow\":496374}]"
```

Comment: Hey i really appreciate your immediate response. but this you are doing from clojure side. I want to do it on client side like in javascript.

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari that *is* client side. `cljs` is clojurescript.

Comment: nope this is all clojurescript. as you question has a clojurescript tag - I assumed you have clojurescript on the client side

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari if you want to do it in vanilla *JavaScript*, you'll have to write a custom parsing library.

Comment: Thank you ver much @JaredSmith and birdspider. Can you please provide me a link from where i can begin with.

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari `from where i can begin with` - what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean do you have any solution or someone had already done it. Which can help me out to parse the same

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari writing a reliable parser for even trivial grammars is beyond a "link"... or even the scope of an SO question. I mean you will have to start from *scratch*. Just use clojurescript on the client. Or serialize to JSON on the server.

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari I just spent 4 seconds on google, and found an js/edn parser - good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use EDN parser implemented in JavaScript: [github.com/shaunxcode/jsedn](https://github.com/shaunxcode/jsedn).